# Remove one of URL query strings which passed to URL as array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, query-string

Here is the URL :

```
www.example.com/?param%5B%5D=A&param%5B%5D=B
```

the `%5B%5D`  part is `[]`  to pass `param` as an array, which is encoded in url.

Now, I want to remove one of parameters , desired output is:

```
www.example.com/?param%5B%5D=B
```

I have searched for this but  found nothing! 
All the answers are about removing a single value parameter, not multiple.

**UPDATE:**

I don't  know the exact position of the parameter, i.e the URL could be something like this:

```
www.example.com/?test=124&test2=456&param%5B%5D=A&param%5B%5D=B
```

Comment: Is those params are probably received by a PHP script like `index.php`. So, it should be handled there. If you can't, It has do be handled before the request is sent.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  those are search parameters. I want to remove one of them and reload the page . User should be able to do that in browser by clicking a `x` close button for every parameter

Comment: I see... So you'll have to get the URL and perform string manipulations to split the params... Then use it to rebuild the URL based on user choice (like checkboxes or buttons).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes exactly!  I'm looking for this manipulation!  Tried something amateur like this :  `window.location.href =  url.replace("param%5B%5D=A",'' ");`  but didn't work. I think regex is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to extract the params from the URL.

Now how to use them on a user user interaction form (UI) is up to you.

```js
// Use this to get the document location:
var ActualURL = document.location.href;
console.log("This snippet URL: "+ActualURL);


// Only for this demo, I "simulate" a URL.
// ActualURL is overwritten here.
var ActualURL = "www.example.com/?param%5B%5D=A&param%5B%5D=B";
console.log("FAKED URL: "+ActualURL);

var domain = ActualURL.split("?")[0];
console.log("Domain: "+domain);

var params = ActualURL.split("?")[1];

var param_array = params.split("&");

for (i=0;i<param_array.length;i++){
  console.log( "Param #"+i+": "+param_array[i] );
}

console.log("Rebuilted URL with only param #2: "+domain+"?"+param_array[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that I don't know array index of desired param. I only know the value. e.g. : `param[]=A`  , It could be index=1 or index=2 or 3 . ... we should search It with regex looking for  `A`

Comment: I mean position of  `param[]=A` could be different, example :   `www.example.com/?test=2112&test2=2&param[]=E&param[]=A&param[]=B`

Comment: I get it... But it doesn't matter. You said in comments *«User should be able to do that in browser by clicking a x close button for every parameter»*. So display them all with a checkbox for each... And, on submit, rebuilt the URL with what user has selected. The order REALLY doesn't matter.

Comment: But the form is not entirely  made of only checkboxes . There are some other input[text]  field witch user can type and then click on submit button.  Other inputs can change position of `param[]=A`! I don't know if I should use    `param_array[1]` OR `param_array[2]` OR  ...

Comment: only want to auto submit the form if user change one of checkboxes

Comment: To auto submit on checkbox change, you can try `$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){ $("form").submit(); });`

Comment: yes I know this , I simulated checkboxes in another element with my preferred  UI , I can use your idea and change checkboxes and submit, instead of manipulate the URL and reload!!  Let me try

Comment: :) Super! I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of URL WebAPI.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```js
var base = 'http://www.example.com/'
var query = '?param%5B%5D=A&param%5B%5D=B';

var url = new URL(base + query);

var params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);


var filteredParams = params.getAll('param[]')
  .filter(function(el) {
    return el !== "A";
  }).map(function(el){
    return ['param[]', el];
  });

var newParams = new URLSearchParams(filteredParams);

var url = new URL(base + '?' + newParams.toString() );
console.log(url.toString());
```

Comment: Note that browser support is limited for this API

Comment: Thanks, But I don't know exact position of `param[]=A`. url could be something like this :  `www.example.com/?test=2112&test2=2&param[]=E&param[]=A&param‌​[]=B`

Comment: Thanks Let me try!

Comment: It didn't work in my browser!! thank you. I can show my respect in some other ways!! ;)